# Which of the following statements with respect to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are FALSE?

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function satisfying $$f(x)=x+\int_0^1 \left(xt^2+x^2t\right)f(t)dt$$ and $g(x)$ be a polynomial satisfying $$g(x)+g\left(\frac 1x\right)=g(x)\cdot g\left(\frac 1x\right); g(2)=9$$
> Then which of the following is/are FALSE?

A. $y = f(x)$ and $y = g(x)$ intersect at only two points.

B. $y = f(x)$ is even function.

C. $y = g(x)$ is odd function.

D. $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ do not have a global minima $∀x∈R−\{0\}$.

**My attempt:**

I was not able to do much in this question, especially with $f(x)$.

Using Hit and Trial, I was able to determine $$g(x)=x^3+1$$

But I am completely clueless on how to proceed with $f(x)$.

The given answers are:

> A, B and C

I would appreciate any hints or answers especially on how to deal with $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$ \int_0^1 tf(t)dt=A, \int_0^1t^2f(t)dt= B. $$
Then
$$ f(x)=(1+A)x+Bx^2. $$
Note that
$$ A=\int_0^1xf(x)dx=\int_0^1(1+A)x^2dx+\int_0^1Bx^3dx=\frac{1}{3}(1+A)+\frac14B. \tag1$$
Similarly,
$$ B=\frac{1}{4}(1+A)+\frac15B. \tag2 $$
Solving $A,B$ from (1) and (2), you will get $f(x)$. I omit the detail.